# empty object on form submission Angular 6

Tags: angular, http

I have the following code:

```
html:



    <div id="add">
     <span>ADD ITEM</span>
     <form #formRef ="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addData(formRef.value)">
     <input type='text'>
     <button type='submit'>Add</button>
     </form>
    </div>

 ts:

 addData(data: NgForm) {
        console.log(data);
        this.http.addData(data).subscribe(
          (data: any) => this.getData()
        );
      }

service.ts:

    addData(data: NgForm) {
            this.count++;
            const newData = {
                'name': data,
                'id': this.count
            };
            return this.http.post<Data>(this.Url, data, this.httpOptions);
        }
```

I am submitting the form and when I console data it prints empty object instead of the form data.Where I am going wrong?

update:

```
getData() {
     this.http.getData().subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
       this.randData = data;

      });
  }
```

Added getData code

Comment: post the `getData` function

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka added

Comment: where is the form ? can you add the snippet ?

Comment: You need to print the value in the form. `console.log(data.value);`

Comment: @CruelEngine I have added the form